# How to draw a polygon shaped data annotation shape for image detection?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, polygon, object-recognition, imageai

I am training some images using imageAI object detection. What i want to do is draw a polygon shaped data annotation around the objects in an image. Not a square box. Even though I ca draw the shape, the imageAI class doesn't consider polygon shapes. If some one can help me to find if is there is some model where polygon shapes are allowed in image training, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImageAI only supports PascalVOC image annotation format, which is upright rectangular bounding boxes. You would need to change frameworks for this to work. For a workaround, consider using an image editing tool to get rid of the background and then provide a square bounding box.